# Update post_meta with WooCommere variation data

Tags: post-meta

Iam having a product with multiple variations.
I created custom fields which will show up in the settings of each variation. These fields should hold/duplicate some variation data.

Iam having trouble, saving these fields. On the first save, nothing is updated, only if I save a second time the data is saved.

For example:
I have one product with variations, the first variation has a description of "50x40 cm" and an sku of "12345".

I now have some custom fields called `my_custom_variation_description` and `my_custom_variation_sku`.
The field `my_custom_variation_description` should just show a duplication of the description field, "50x40 cm".
And the `my_custom_variation_sku` should just duplicate the variation sku, "12345".

To create the fields Iam using the hook `woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes`.
And here I can fill in my fields for example with data like `$get_description = $variation_data['_variation_description'][0];` and `$get_sku = $variation_data['_sku'][0];`.

Than I save these data to custom fields, in my `woocommerce_save_product_variation` like...

```
$custom_sku = $_POST['my_custom_variation_sku'][ $variation_id ];
update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'my_custom_variation_sku', $custom_sku );
```

So, this setup is kind of working, the problem which Iam having is:

After I change the description of the variation for example to "50x40 cmxxx" and save the product. The output of `get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'my_custom_variation_description', true );` is still shows "50x40 cm" and not "50x40 cmxxx".

Only if I now save the product again (using the default wordpress publish/update button), or save the variation setting (using the "Save variation changes" button below the variation list), the data gets updated.

I created variation fields in the past, and there was not such a problem saving the fields.
So I imagine I must be doing something wrong here.

I also tried different save functions including:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );  
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 1 );  
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 1 );  
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );
```

Sample screenshot:
[image: sample screenshot]